# Android ProgressBar interfering with GCM registration

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an app which uses Google Cloud Messaging. The app can register for a new registration ID without any issues. However, if I display an indeterminate ProgressBar during the registration period, the registration fails with error `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`. The app also takes a visibly longer time at attempting registration before failing.

The ProgressBar is declared in the main activity's layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActivityLogin" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/hello_world" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBarMain"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ProgressBar is shown immediately before beginning the registration:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...

        if (reg.isEmpty())
        {
            progressBarMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            reg.registerInBackground(context, this);
        }
    }
}
```

`registerInBackground()` runs an AsyncTask which makes the GCM call and returns the result to this callback:

```java
public void completeRegistration(RegistrationResult result)
{
    if (result.success == true)
    {
        textHelloWorld.append("Registered new ID: " + result.registrationId);
    }
    else
    {
        textHelloWorld.append("Failed to register new ID. Reason: " + getString(result.messageId));
    }
    progressBarMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Simply commenting out the two `progressBarMain.setVisibility()` calls lets the whole thing run smooth as butter, but as long as they're included registration doesn't seem to be possible.

I have tested this on a real device running 2.3.3 and an emulator running 4.4. Both display the same behaviour. I also tried running the AsyncTask with the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` but this made no difference.